# What does "CXXABI_x.y" mean?

Tags: linux, rpm, abi

My RPM package has this in its dependencies list:

```
libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)  
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)
```

What do the strings in parenthesis mean? And if it is an ABI version, how can I change, replace or delete the dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your installed gcc/libstdc++ you may need a more recent libstdc++

See also http://glandium.org/blog/?p=1901 and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

For basic info you can also read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

You can'd change, replace, or delete the dependency. If it's required, it's required. You can force it to install but it'll be broken (won't launch).

What you could do is to recompile the code from source.